# how make jfrog artifactory post to custom webhook endpoint on artifactory updates

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, jfrog-container-registry

I'm pretty new to jfrog artifactory.  Is there a way to tell jfrog artifactory to POST to a custom endpoint/webhook whenever a new artifactory version of a repo is published? I'm trying to create a slack notification to my team whenever a new artifactory version is published.  I've seen some examples with Artifactory pipelines but nothing very specific.  Thanks!

Comment: Artifactory's "built-in" event service will be released in one of the upcoming versions. In the meantime, you can use this user plugin - https://jfrog.com/blog/automation-using-webhooks-in-jfrog-artifactory/.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment by Ortsigat, the support for webhooks was released as part of [Artifactory 7.6](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Release+Notes#ArtifactoryReleaseNotes-Artifactory7.6). Webhooks can be managed via the web UI or the REST API.
You can read more about it in the Artifactory [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Webhooks).